# Angular JS login with java rest api as backend

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, angularjs

So I am creating a login functionality with Java and MySQL as the backend and AngularJS, HTML as the front-end. If I put in valid email and password, it logins in correctly, but if I put invalid email and password, it also logins. I am not sure how to resolve this. I was thinking for the user service class, instead of returning a User object, return a boolean. Then when I call the post method on angularJS, I could check if the var res is true or false. I am not sure if there is another way or a better way

User Service

```
// Checking if the user can login successfully
    public User login(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            User dbUser = new User();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, user.getEmail());

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();

            dbUser.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            dbUser.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
            dbUser.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
            dbUser.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            dbUser.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            dbUser.setPhoneNum(rs.getString("phonenum"));

            if(user.getEmail().equals(dbUser.getEmail()) && 
                    user.getPassword().equals(dbUser.getPassword()))
            {
                System.out.println("Successfully Logged-In");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Failed To Log-In");
                dbUser = null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

User Resource

```
@Path("/login")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void login(User user)
    {
        userService.login(user);

    }
```

login.js

```
var app = angular.module("loginApp", []);

app.controller("loginController", function($scope, $http) {

    // POST METHOD.... Checking if the login is successfull
    $scope.checkLogin = function() {
        // retrieving the data from the login form
        var dataObj = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
        };

        if($scope.email.length === 0 || typeof $scope.email === 'undefined'
        && $scope.password.length === 0 || typeof $scope.password === 'undefined') {
            console.log("pls enter something");
        }else {
            console.log("something entered");
            var res = $http.post("http://localhost:8080/quiz/webapi/account/login", dataObj).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

        function successCallback(res){
            console.log("Successfully Connected to Login API");
            console.log("Redirecting to dashboard page");
            window.location = "http://localhost:8080/quiz_webclient/dashboard.html";
        }
        function errorCallback(error){
            console.log("Faile To Connect to Login API");
        }
    };

    $scope.cancelLogin = function() {
        console.log("Redirecting to home page");
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/quiz_webclient/homepage.html";
    }
});
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cs/login.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginController">
        <form class="loginForm">
            <label id="label">Email</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" required> <br>
            <label id="passwordlabel">Password</label> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" required> <br>

            <button type="submit" ng-click="checkLogin()">Login</button> <br>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="cancelLogin()">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the output? do you get `Successfully Logged-In` when it is meant to fail?

Comment: No I get Failed To Log-In when it fails but it still logs in

Answer (score 0):

Use dots in your model names (e.g.)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="loginData.email" autofocus required>
```

Also, with respect to the POST operation - it would help to know which version of angular you are using. However, If you are using Angular version < 1.6 I would try using .success() and .error() methods directly instead of .then. Something like:

```
    $scope.checkLogin = function() {
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/quiz/webapi/account/login", $scope.loginData)
          .success(function(data) {
              window.location = "http://localhost:8080/quiz_webclient/dashboard.html";
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log('Error: ' + data);
          });
    };
```

I don't know enough about Java to comment on what might be happening there. Would consider using Node.js instead. and your authentication method could return a token instead of a user or boolean.